# How to make div fall beside previous div

Tags: html, css

Hello all I have two images that switch on hover. in the divs they are currently in the images overlap, both starting at the top of the div as opposed to beside it.[example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jpgzj3ecbbg730c/Capture.PNG)

```
<div class="storyboard">

<div class="storycard" >
    <img src="Images/Articles/Index/world%20cup2.jpg" class="primary">
    <img src="Images/Articles/Index/world%20cup.jpg" class="secondary">
</div>

<div class="storycard">
   <img src="Images/Articles/Index/ntci2.jpg" class="primary">
   <img src="Images/Articles/Index/ntci1.jpg" class="secondary">
</div>
```

and my css

```
 .storyboard{
     width: 100%;
     padding: 30px;

 }

.storycard{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
 }

.storycard img{
    position: absolute;
     margin: 0 auto;

}

.storycard .secondary:hover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
  -webkit-opacity: 0;
  -moz-opacity: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  display: block;
}
```

Due to the .storycard .secondry:hover as it is I cant make the .storycard img relative other wise I get [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/k0h4jnr9x6t6jwc/Capture1.PNG). Thanks.

Comment: please provide a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

First of all enclose your all `div` elements in a `#wrapper`.
and set the `display` of `#wrapper` to `display:inline-block;`

```
#wrapper{
 width: 100%;
 padding: 30px;
display:inline-block;
}
```

Then give different `class` to both  `div` elements inside the `#wrapper` 
See the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L87L3/2/)